# how does pthread_join populate the variable of thread_result

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, ubuntu-10.04

Note: I have removed all required error checking in the following snippet.

```
...
void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
   ...
   pthread_exit("Hello");
}

pthread_t a_thread;
void *thread_result;

pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
/*

int pthread_join(pthread_t th, void **thread_return);
The second argument is a pointer to a pointer that itself points to the return
value from the thread.

int pthread_exit(void *retval);
This function terminates the calling thread, returning a pointer to an object which
cannot be a local variable.

*/
```

**Question**: how does pthread_join populate the variable of thread_result?
Since the variable thread_result has no allocated space to hold information,
if pthread_join allocates space for thread_result, then major thread must
deallocate the resource holding by the varable. As you can see, the code doesn't
include the deallocation resource of thread_result. So I assume that pthread_join
in fact doesn't allocate space for thread_result.

Now the new question is how the variable thread_result can contain information without
being allocated any space?

//Update-1: Add the definition of pthread_exit.

//Update-2: Add the definition of thread_function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct: `pthread_join` doesn't allocate memory for the result.

In fact, what happens is quite simple:

- `pthread_exit` is provided a (`void*`) pointer to the result by the thread itself; it's up to the thread to decide where this pointer comes from.
- Subsequently, `pthread_join` -- called from another thread -- stores that pointer in the variable pointed to by its second argument.

As far as the result is concerned, all that `pthreads` is doing is passing a pointer across thread boundaries. It is up to the application to ensure that the pointed-to memory is deallocated in a manner that's consistent with how it's been allocated.

Answer (score 2):

`thread_result` is simply a pointer to the data that `thread_function` returns. If `thread_function` returns an `int` cast to `void *`, the thread calling `pthread_join` must be aware of this and treat `thread_result` as `int`. If on the other hand `thread_function` returns a pointer to allocated memory, the thread calling `pthread_join` must be aware of this and eventually free the memory.

In your example, where `thread_function` returns a string literal, `thread_result` will be a pointer to the string literal. It's the same as this:

```
 const char *str = "Hello";
```

String literals are generally allocated in the data section, so you shouldn't free them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `pthread_join` doesn't allocate anything. You've got your thread function

```
void *thread_fun(void *arg)
{
    /* stuff */


    return something;
}
```

Then `pthread_join` comes along, and before it returns:

```
if (NULL != value_ptr) {
    *value_ptr = return_value; /* What you returned from your function. */
}
```

So the thread function must allocate stuff.

Comment: Thread function not always has to allocate resource. For example, pls see my updated definition for the thread_function which doesn't allocate resource instead, simply returning a const string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thread_result appears to be declared as a pointer. Pointer does not really need a allocated space to hold information. The pointer will be pointed to the memory address returned from the pthread_join.

And more importantly, you have to malloc the result that you are going to return at the end of the thread_function, otherwise, heap memory will be gone.

Sometime in the later, you will eventually have to free the memory space allocated where thread_result points to.

Answer (score 0):

What user482594 said

Also:

> [The  pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates,
>          unless the target thread has already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join() call with  a  non-
>          NULL  value_ptr argument, the value passed to pthread_exit() by the terminating thread shall be made available
>          in the location referenced by value_ptr. When a pthread_join() returns successfully,  the  target  thread  has
>          been  terminated.  The  results  of  multiple  simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target
>          thread are undefined. If the thread calling pthread_join() is canceled, then the target thread  shall  not  be
>          detached.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join)